# How do I organize my css better so that separate a tags don't get the same styling?

Tags: javascript, css, styling

This is how my index.php should [look](https://codepen.io/SuperN00b/pen/rjKOaP) (codepen link)

I'm trying to add javascript functions to the buttons on the right. However, there is a styling issue that messes the buttons up. This is what [happened](https://codepen.io/SuperN00b/pen/zNavYX).

As you can see the log in button has taken the styling of the a tags for the footer.

I don't know much about javascript and got the code from a tutorial I found. I would rather not change the javascript. I'm sure that I probably need to organize my html or css better. If anyone has any tips, I would really appreciate it. I've been stuck on this for two days.

The only way I was able to move the button was styling it in html button

ex:

`<a id="loginbutton" href="javascript:toggle();" style="top: 220px;">log in</a>` 
I don't like this solution because I'm going to want to make the webpage responsive. I need to be able to make media queries in the stylesheet.

SUMMARY:

1. When I added the javacript, the styling for the footer tag links (a tag) messes up my button styling.
2. This needs to be styled in the css file, not the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave the html and css as in your example titled 'working'. You don't need to add the  tag to make the javascript work. You can also use the onclick Event. Just change your button code to:

```
<button class="login" onclick="javascript:toggle();">log in </button>
```

Read more about the onclick event here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: This works but I want a form to drop down on click. Like this -> http://codepen.io/SuperN00b/pen/ygEeWg

Comment: The form will drop down on click if you use the code I provided. You don't necessarily have to use an a tag. Did you try it?

Comment: please take a look at what I've [edited](http://codepen.io/SuperN00b/pen/GrGZMJ) . The form is in the footer and it is not toggling, it's just there.

Comment: Here you have a pen that is working: http://codepen.io/lukaphp/pen/wgXGpz. Your code didn't work because it didn't correctly get the form by ID. I have added an ID to the form and cleaned up the js a bit. Also I added display none for the form in the css

Comment: PERFECT! thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can work with combined css classes or hierachy.

E.g.

**Combined Tags:**

```
.my-tag {
    color: red;
}

.my-tag.footer {
    color: blue;
}
```

**Hierarchy:**

```
.my-tag {
    color: red;
}

.footer .my-tag {
    color: blue;
}
```